# HP DeskJet Plus Ink Advantage 6075 All-in-One Printer - Scanner not working Linux Mint 19.3

Tags: linux-mint, configuration, scanner

I have an HP DeskJet Plus Ink Advantage 6075 All-in-One Printer. Unfortunately the scanner is not detected by any of these programs: Simple Scan, XSane, hp-uiScan.
In the first place it didn't work even as a printer, but after downloading hplip-3.20.11.run
and using the following command in terminal:
cd ~/Downloads/ && chmod +x hplip-3.20.11.run && ./hplip-3.20.11.run
it finally prints.
After using terminal command hp-plugin, it tried to download some plugin, but did not succseed.
Now hp-plugin command isn't working any more, following message appears:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/hp-plugin", line 41, in 
from base import device, utils, tui, module, services
File "/usr/share/hplip/base/device.py", line 42, in 
from . import status
File "/usr/share/hplip/base/status.py", line 50, in 
import hpmudext
ImportError: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/hpmudext.so: undefined symbol: ipAddressBuff

To be mentioned, I tried a lot of methods, don't even remember what. Nothing works.
Now, even hp-uiscan does not start any more.

So what to do in order to make tha scanner work ?
Is there a method to install the printer in the first place, so that it works as printer and scanner ?

Comment: You should first install the drivers: https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/gethplip since that will give you system wide access to the hardware without having to run the downloaded version. Then `cups` and the scanner tools might be able to pick it up (it is not listed [here](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/supported_devices/index))

Comment: But I already downloaded and installed hplip-3.20.11.run. it is not enough. It asks for a plugin, something, that it is not able to download.
So where can I get a scanner plugin ?

Comment: You downloaded it and run locally, ok. The thing with package software is that it will put everything where it is supposed to be, including plugins. I'd give it a try. Usually it is better (and somehow safer) to install a package for your distribution than to trust a install script. Then again, it might not change anything.